# PeerJS prompt with name of caller?

Tags: javascript, webrtc, peerjs

Background info to issue :
I am using PeerJS and I have a div I am show on the call event which serves as a modal for accepting or declining a call.

Question :
Is there a way that I can send a username along with the call request (aside from the ID of the peer, I am using UUID's for that) so that I can have the div say "Username" is calling?

Thankyou in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the [PeerJS documentation](http://peerjs.com/docs/) it says that you can attach metadata to a peer.connect call, like this:

```
var conn = peer.connect(peerID, { metadata: { userName: 'name goes here' } });
```

Then you can access the metadata like this:

```
peer.on('connection', function(conn) {
    var userName = conn.metadata.userName;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `call.peer`

USAGE:

```
//peer1
const peer = new Peer('1')

peer.call('2', stream)
```

```
//peer2
const peer = new Peer('2')

peer.on('call', (call)=> {
console.log(call.peer)
})
```

Above code will Log '1'

Answer (score -1):

you can use
 
`div.innerHTML=call.peer`

this shows the id of peer which trying to make you a connection.